# Ocultar imagen al cargar pagina por medio de onchange function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo para mostrar la imagen cuando la pagina carga al hacer POST por medio de un select:

**esta es la imagen:**

```
<img src="img/icons/loader_transp.gif" width="20px" id="searchingimageDiv" class="img_loading" style="display:none">
```

**este codigo del post del select:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Div2").change(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"../../../controllers/mi.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:"V="+$("#Div2").val(),
                    success: function(opciones){
                        $("#div_view").html(opciones);

                    }
                })
            });
        });
```

**este es el codigo de mostrar la imagen :**

```
  $(window).load(function(){
      $('#Div2').on("change", function(){
         $('#searchingimageDiv').toggle();
      });
   });
```

El problema viene luego de hacer el post, la imagen la muestra, pero no se oculta automáticamente al terminar de cargar la pagina, que puedo estar haciendo mal, alguna sugerencia

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Te puede servir asi?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("#Div2").change(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"../../../controllers/mi.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:"V="+$("#Div2").val(),
                    success: function(opciones){
                        $("#div_view").html(opciones);
                      $('#searchingimageDiv').toggle();
                    }
                })
            });
        });
```

Comment: excelente gracias @Pedro Quiñonez esto si me funciono

Comment: Como agregado te sugiero que cada vez que utilices ajax asignes una funcion callback en caso de error.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Alexander si lo que deseas hacer es ocultar la imagen al momento de cargar la página deberias colocar este código en el mismo document ready $("#searchingimageDiv").hide():

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Div2").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:"../../../controllers/mi.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:"V="+$("#Div2").val(),
        success: function(opciones){
            $("#div_view").html(opciones);

        }
    })
});
$("#searchingimageDiv").hide();});
```

Si lo necesitas realizar de otra manera cuéntanos más detallado tu problema para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Hola @Stalin Caiche, es exactamente la idea que busco de acuerdo a tu sugerencia, pero no me funciono , en todo caso la idea es que cuando hago el onchange en el select un codigo me muestra la imagen , el que mencione alla arriba pero luego de hacer este post  desde el select, la imagen se queda cargando y no desaparece.

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que al momento de hacer el change en el select se muestra la imagen (que hasta ahí todo lo tienes bien), pero este change del select también realiza un ajax. y deseas que después del ajax la imagen se oculte. verdad? si es así prueba colocando el $("#searchingimageDiv").hide(); al final del ajax.